# How to switch to another state at the end of a transition in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to implement a fitness application that displays the current exercise name then shows a progress bar during the resting periods. When the progress bar is fully filled, the name of the next exercise is displayed, then a progress bar is shown when it is completed, and so on.

Note that I'm using a progress bar for this example but I'll have my own widget in the real application.

My system has two states :

- **exercise** the value of the progress bar is 0 and stays 0
- **rest** the value of the progress bar goes from 0 to maximumValue over the duration of the resting period

So it goes like this :

1. the application is in "exercise" state and shows the name of the current exercicse
2. the user execute the exercise and click on the progress bar when he's done
3. the application switches to the "rest" state
4. the user rests while the progress bar is being completed
5. after the progress bar is completed the application switches back to the "exercise" state and displays the name of the next exercise

My issue is with step 5 : I do not know how to switch back to another state at the end of a transition. I've tried to change the "state" property during a PropertyChanges and time it at the end of a transition with a SequentialAnimation, but I get this error message :

> QML StateGroup: Can't apply a state change as part of a state definition.

Here is some sample code :

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

ProgressBar {
    id: root

    width: 200
    height: 48

    minimumValue: 0
    maximumValue: 100
    value: 76

    function switchState() {
        if (state == "exercise")
        {
            state = "rest"
            return
        }

        if (state == "rest")
        {
            state = "exercise"
            return
        }
    }

    state: "exercise"

    states: [
        State {
            name: "exercise"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: root
                value: 0
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "rest"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: root
                value: maximumValue

                // error: QML StateGroup: Can't apply a state change as part of a state definition.
                // state: "exercise"
            }
        }
    ]

    transitions: [
        Transition {
            to: "rest"
            PropertyAnimation {
                target: root
                properties: "value"
                duration: 1000
            }
        }
    ]

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: parent.switchState()
    }
}
```

How can I switch to another state at the end of a state transition ?

Comment: One option would be to trigger a Timer at the end and do the state change from the timer tick.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you can do this by using the RunningChanged signal from the transition:

```
transitions: [
    Transition {
        to: "rest"
        PropertyAnimation {
            target: root
            properties: "value"
            duration: 1000
        }

        onRunningChanged: {
            if ((state == "rest") && (!running))
                switchState();
        }
    }
]
```

QML Objects have an associated signal for property changes (`on<Property>Changed`). The associated handlers are usually not documented in the objects' references, but are implicitly available due to the property's existence. See [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-change-signals).

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**
I proposed a wrong solution because a mistake, so excuse me please.
Fixing its problem results same solution as @GabrielF one. So I deleted it to avoid repeating.

*However below solution works great and gives you fine control within a Transition/Animaiton.*

**Also another way!**

```
transitions: [
    Transition {
        to: "rest"
        SequentialAnimation {
            PropertyAnimation {
                target: root
                properties: "value"
                duration: 1000
            }
            ScriptAction { script: switchState() }    //<----
        }
    }
]
```

Please note that with `SequentialAnimation` within a transition animation, you don't need to define a middle state, if you like to just ensure that an specific animation is completed.

Goodluck - S.M.Mousavi

Comment: According to the [docs on the `stopped` signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-animation.html#stopped-signal), "It is only triggered for top-level, standalone animations. It will not be triggered for animations in a Behavior or Transition, or animations that are part of an animation group." so your first and second examples would not work I think.

Comment: I really like the approach in your last example, I'm now using it in my app and it works great.

Comment: I prefer this solution using `SequentialAnimation{... ScriptAction{ script: ...} }` but the second `PropertyAnimation` is misleading and doesn't relate to the OP's question so I cannot upvote (yet). NB: The curly braces around `switchState()` aren't necessary.

Comment: What happens when the state is changed during the transition? Will the sequential animation run to end and execute the script action? Can't find it in the docs

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Transition behavior is like that: if you change state during the transition, it will stop(pause) that transition and start suitable one from current values.