# Changing state after a transition's animations have finished

Tags: qt, animation, qml, state, transition

I'd like to change state after a transition's animations have completed. I have the following code that achieves this, although it seems kind of hackish:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        color: "blue"
        width: 50
        height: 50
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: rect.state = "animating"
        }

        states: [
            State {
                name: "animating"

                PropertyChanges {
                    target: rect
                    rotation: 360
                }
            },
            State {
                name: "shrinking"

                PropertyChanges {
                    target: rect
                    scale: 0
                }
            }
        ]

        transitions: [
            Transition {
                from: ""
                to: "animating"

                SequentialAnimation {
                    RotationAnimation {
                        duration: 500
                    }
                    ScriptAction {
                        script: rect.state = "shrinking"
                    }
                }
            },
            Transition {
                from: "animating"
                to: "shrinking"

                NumberAnimation {
                    property: "scale"
                    duration: 500
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a nicer way to do this without using `ScriptAction`? Note that I need the second state, and I don't want to just consolidate the scale animation into the `SequentialAnimation` of the `animating` transition.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902769/how-to-switch-to-another-state-at-the-end-of-a-transition-in-qml but your existing solution is cleaner than the original question's answer.

Comment: I don't even like my solution, so I hope there's a better one. :p

Comment: The fact that your state is named "shrinking" instead of "shrunk" is a sign that they are not real states, but transitions implemented as states. Can't you merge both transitions with a SequentialAnimation?

Comment: @jturcotte Yeah, the naming is not the best, but the point here is that I am after a nice way of having state changes that are done at the end of a transition. The question that cmannett85 mentioned makes me think that I'm not the only one wondering how to do this.

Comment: My point is that if the state isn't triggered in response to a user or system event, it is only a transitional state. In the linked example, the {to: "rest"} transition isn't actually a transition to the rest state, the transition is the implementation the exercise state itself.

It feels like a PropertyAnimation outside of a transition, with its running property triggered as part of the state change or onClicked would be a cleaner solution. What's missing is maybe a onCompleted signal on Animation to trigger the state back, but onRunningChanged could also be used.

Comment: @jturcotte I think I understand what you're saying, but I have the feeling that I'm going to run into this situation again. If/when that happens, I'll see if I can do it like you're suggesting, otherwise I'll come back and respond with the problems I had. :)

Answer (score -1):

A slightly different approach is to set the `shrinking` state in the `animating` state, and use a `PropertyAction` to force the state change to happen at the end of the transition:

```
        State {
            name: "animating"

            PropertyChanges {
                target: rect
                rotation: 360
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: rect
                state: "shrinking"
            }
```

and

```
        Transition {
            SequentialAnimation {
                RotationAnimation {
                    duration: 500
                }
                PropertyAction {
                    target: rect
                    property: "state"
                }
            }
        }
```

Note that I agree with jturcotte on his assessment of using these states here.

Comment: This doesn't work: `QML StateGroup: Can't apply a state change as part of a state definition.`

Comment: Didn't know that this does not work for state changes of the item itself (makes sense though). I frequently use this approach where the root item triggers state changes of various children in its state change. You can still make this work by e.g. using two helper `Item`s, `shrinkstate` and `animatingstate`, defining the state changes there and then triggering their state changes from the parent rectangle. Very cumbersome here but can be the cleaner solution if the rest of the qml and state changes become more involved.

Answer (score -1):

The proper way is to change the state in the `runningChanged` handler of the transition, when running pass to false than the animation finished. 
to do that you have two solutions:

Sol 1. use `connections` ( you will get a warning about a none notifiable property, ignore it)

```
Connections{
            target:rect.transitions[0]

            onRunningChanged:{
                if( rect.transitions[0].running === false)
                {
                    rect.state = "shrinking"
                }
            }
        }
```

the code will be :

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        color: "blue"
        width: 50
        height: 50
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: rect.state = "animating"
        }

        states: [
            State {
                name: "animating"

                PropertyChanges {
                    target: rect
                    rotation: 360
                }
            },
            State {
                name: "shrinking"

                PropertyChanges {
                    target: rect
                    scale: 0
                }
            }
        ]
        Connections{
            target:rect.transitions[0]

            onRunningChanged:{
                if( rect.transitions[0].running === false)
                {
                    rect.state = "shrinking"
                }
            }
        }
        transitions: [
            Transition {
                from: ""
                to: "animating"
                    RotationAnimation {
                        duration: 500
                    }
            },
            Transition {
                from: "animating"
                to: "shrinking"

                NumberAnimation {
                    property: "scale"
                    duration: 500
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

solution 2:
change state in `runningchanged` handler in the transition directly:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        color: "blue"
        width: 50
        height: 50
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: rect.state = "animating"
        }

        states: [
            State {
                name: "animating"

                PropertyChanges {
                    target: rect
                    rotation: 360
                }
            },
            State {
                name: "shrinking"

                PropertyChanges {
                    target: rect
                    scale: 0
                }
            }
        ]

        transitions: [
            Transition {
                from: ""
                to: "animating"

                    RotationAnimation {
                        duration: 500
                    }
                    onRunningChanged:{
                        if( running === false)
                        {
                            rect.state = "shrinking"
                        }
                    }
            },
            Transition {
                from: "animating"
                to: "shrinking"

                NumberAnimation {
                    property: "scale"
                    duration: 500
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I prefer the first solution (`Connections`) cause it's more generic

Comment: I wouldn't call this the proper way at all, just like my solution doesn't feel proper. I still don't think there is a nice way to do this.

Comment: I meant by proper way, that I think that the developper of Qt created the signal runningChanged to be used like that, it's nicer than using a ScriptAction. if not than what is the point of emiting this signal :)

Comment: There are lots of ways of changing the state, but they're either all imperative instead of declarative, or they just feel... yucky. :p I think a `nextState` property would be really nice to have in the `State` object. I need to come up with a better example though, as I think @jturcotte is correct about my original one, in that it could just be two animations.